# How to add an index label using pandas MultiIndex.insert to an existing MultiIndex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

With below code I tried to insert a new row label (two name-levels) but it appears that `MultiIndex.insert()` does not work according to the printed output. User xyzjayne mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309742/pandas-multiindex-add-labels-to-an-index-level) ***"MultiIndex is immutable"***. Then why is there `MultiIndex.insert` and/or how to use `MultiIndex.insert` properly in below case to get desired result?

**NOT** an option:

> add ('D', '9') to `labels` tuple list before MultiIndexing.
>   This `labels` is general, has a default list order and is used a few times elsewhere in different settings. And thus prior to the creation of a DataFrame.

Versions :`pandas  0.25.1  py37ha925a31_0`

Desired result:

```py
row_labels MultiIndex([('A', '1'),
                       ('A', '2'),
                       ('B', '3'),
                       ('B', '4'),
                       ('C', '5'),
                       ('C', '6'),
                       ('D', '9'),   # inserted row label ('D', '9')
                       ('D', '7'),
                       ('D', '8')],
                       names=['group', 'subgroup'])
```

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd

labels = {'A' : ['1', '2'],
          'B' : ['3', '4'],
          'C' : ['5', '6'],
          'D' : ['7', '8']}

tpl = []

for g, sg in labels.items():
  for s in sg:
    tpl.append((g, s))

row_labels = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tpl, names=['group', 'subgroup'])

print ('row_labels', row_labels)

i = row_labels.get_locs(('D',))

print ('\nD is found at row(s): ', i)

# add row at position 6
row_labels.insert(6, (('D', '9')))

# check for added label
print ('\nrow_labels', row_labels)
```

My current output:

```py
row_labels MultiIndex([('A', '1'),
                       ('A', '2'),
                       ('B', '3'),
                       ('B', '4'),
                       ('C', '5'),
                       ('C', '6'),
                       ('D', '7'),
                       ('D', '8')],
                       names=['group', 'subgroup'])

D is found at row(s):  [6 7]

row_labels MultiIndex([('A', '1'),
                       ('A', '2'),
                       ('B', '3'),
                       ('B', '4'),
                       ('C', '5'),
                       ('C', '6'),
                       ('D', '7'),
                       ('D', '8')],
                       names=['group', 'subgroup'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign back, [`Index.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.insert.html) not working inplace:

```
print (pd.__version__)
0.25.1

# add row at position 6
row_labels = row_labels.insert(6, (('D', '9')))

# check for added label
print ('\nrow_labels', row_labels)
row_labels MultiIndex([('A', '1'),
            ('A', '2'),
            ('B', '3'),
            ('B', '4'),
            ('C', '5'),
            ('C', '6'),
            ('D', '9'),
            ('D', '7'),
            ('D', '8')],
           names=['group', 'subgroup'])
```

Comment: .. I just figured `# add row at position 6
row_labels = pd.MultiIndex.insert(row_labels, 6, ('D', '9'))` out... but still in docs pandas 0.19 it mentions MultiIndex (loc, items).

Comment: @ZF007 - My opinion - this function is used very rare, so maybe buggy. Obviously is MultiIndex converted to list of tuples or to DataFrames, procesing and then convert back to `Multiindex`.

Comment: Yeah.. buggy indeed. Thanks for jumping in. It saves me an hour or two of headachs on this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the discussion with jezrael the .insert appears to be sloppy made or missing text at the docs.

My alternative also works:

`row_labels = pd.MultiIndex.insert(row_labels, 6, ('D', '9'))`

And is not as such described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/indexing.html#multiindex) at the pandas docs 0.25.0 .

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.insert.html) at 0.19.0 it is and the text should be:

> MultiIndex.insert(index, loc, item)

and thus missing the previous made "MultiIndex" as "Index".